# Why is this HMAC SHA256 hash I'm creating using the wrong character encoding?

Tags: c#, encoding, sha, hmac

I'm doing this in C# to create a hash:

```
using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret)))
{
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hmacsha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message)));
}
```

I use the following JSON:

```
{
    "client_id": "26075235",
    "client_version": "1.0.0",
    "event": "app.uninstall",
    "timestamp": "1478741247",
    "data": {
        "user_id": "62581379",
        "site_id": "837771289247593785",
        "domain": ""
    }
}
```

and I get `sX�m�.-�n�0�v@�i!S��IEC,�56`

I'm expecting the hash to look like this:

960aff6c335a87e6077f41066358980a88db54062505875e5a8c363ded9d027e

If I do the hashing like this:

```
using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret)))
{
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hmacsha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)));
}
```

I get the same thing. How do I return what I'm expecting?

What am I not understanding about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An arbitrary binary data can not be converted to string... Seems like you want [`BitConverter.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) ,  [`Convert.ToBase64String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapBase64Binary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soapbase64binary(v=vs.110).aspx), instead of `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString`

Comment: Thanks, however BitConverter.ToString gives me 73-58-EE-6D-81-2E-15-1D-14-2D-8F-6E-F1-30-85-76-40-D3-69-14-21-53-A6-D7-49-45-43-2C-D8-35-13-36. Any idea?

Comment: @Izzy idea for what? what is your new problem now?

Comment: Thanks LB - my message for hashing wasn't correct and it threw me. When I hash the correct message now, and removing the '-', it works - see my answer for a fairly neat way to hash a message

Answer (score 2):

Solved now. I use this string extension method, so to get a lowercase HMAC SHA 256 Hash for a string, I can just do:

mymessage.HmacSha256Digest(mysecret)

```
public static string HmacSha256Digest(this string message, string secret)
{
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
    byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
    System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 cryptographer = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(keyBytes);

    byte[] bytes = cryptographer.ComputeHash(messageBytes);

    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}
```